# Calculation of relative strength index (RSI) trading indicator not matching trading view RSI

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

I've been trying to calculate the trading indicator relative strength index (RSI) in NodeJS for well over 2 days now. I have used every RSI calculation and technical indicator package I could find on the internet. None of them so far match any displayed RSI indicators I'm referencing in both my personal brokerage chart and also trading view (of which show the same RSI values).

Trading view claims this to be the formula they used for RSI.

[image]

source: https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502338-relative-strength-index-rsi/

The `rma()` function stands for "relative moving average". Below is the formula supposedly used to calculate relative moving average. Where `26.50` in this example is the current price and `26` is the previous day price.

[image]

source: https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/ema-versus-rma/

The alpha variable is a period based weight applied to the source value.

I've implemented these calculations in nodejs using the following:

```
let change;
let gain = [];
let loss = [];

for (i = 0; i < closingPrices.length - 1; i++) {
    change = closingPrices[i + 1] - closingPrices[i];

    // add gains
    if (change >= 0) {
        gain.push(change);
    } else {
        gain.push(0);
    }

    // add loses
    if (change < 0) {
        loss.push(-1 * change);
    } else {
        loss.push(0);
    }
}

// calculation of relative moving average (defined by trading view)
function RMA(source, length) {
    let rma = (1 / length) * source[0] + (1 - (1 / length) * source[1]);
    return rma;
}

let avgGain = RMA(gain, 14);
let avgLoss = RMA(loss, 14);
let rs = avgGain / avgLoss;
let rsi = 100 - 100 / (1 + rs);
```

`closingPrices` is an array of closing prices for every trading day over the past year to now for a given stock. I have verified this data with every stock, it is completely accurate to all historical records. I'm confident about this because calculation of every other indicator such as SMA has been correct. I'm only having trouble accurately calculating RSI.

I ran this RSI indicator script above for Shopify's stock ("SHOP"). These were the results.

`console.log(rsi)` = 49.43%

However the true RSI value displayed on trading view was 42.20%

So it's simply incorrect. I'm beginning to exhaust every resource I can find to correctly calculate RSI. And yes I have tried all three known methods. I've tried RSI with a simple moving average, RSI with an exponential moving average, and RSI with wilder's smoothing method. None of them match trading view or my brokerage's RSI indicator values.

This appears to be a common community issue. I've only come across one source where someone wrote a script in python for RSI which does correctly match trading view's RSI.

Here is their script:
https://gist.github.com/jmoz/1f93b264650376131ed65875782df386

I'm not familiar with python so I can't read it. Perhaps someone with more familiarity with python can translate this to javascript for me.

Comment: I don't think I fully understood your problem, but it seems weird to me that in your RMA function you are using `source[1]` as the last factor, but in the picture provided it says `RMA[1]` which looks to me as though it were some sort of recursion and not just a previous value of source.

Comment: If you follow the formula down, you can see RMA[1] is just 26. So it simply represents the previous day price. So source[0] is the current price and source[1] is the previous day’s price.

Comment: Ah ok...yeah I wasn't sure if that was what it meant

Comment: Did you try other (existing) technical indicator libraries on the same data? Do you see the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
(1 - (1 / length) * source[1]);
```

to

```
((1 - (1 / length)) * rma[1]);
```

Note both parentesis and it should be previous calculated rma value, not previous source value.

Answer (score 1):

Trandingview uses the following formula to calculate the RMA (a type of EMA used in RSI):

```
RMA = alpha * source + (1 - alpha) * EMA[1] Where alpha = 1 / lenght
```

This formula incorporates the EMA[1], which represents the EMA value from the previous period. If you calculate the EMA without considering this value, your result may differ. To achieve consistency with TradingView's calculations, make sure to include this previous period EMA value, and you should observe that the results match those in TradingView.